# How to prevent Function B returning 'none' to Function A that calls it, after function B calls function C and returns to itself

Tags: python

Apologies for the confusing title, but here is a very simplified version of what I mean:

```
def main():
    burger = 0
    shake = 0

    run = True
    while run:
        choice = show_menu()

        if choice == "burger":
            qt_burger += 1
        elif choice == "shake":
            qt_shake += 1
        else:
            show_bill

def show_menu():
    choice = input("Burger or Shake?: ")
    if choice not in ["burger", "shake"]:
        show_error(choice)
    else:
        return choice

def show_error(choice):
    print(f"{choice} is not an option")
    show_menu()

main()
```

Function 'main' defines variable 'choice' based on what is returned from function 'show_menu'. If show_menu does not call show_error, the program properly returns the input value back to 'choice' in 'main'. However, if show_error is called, show_menu is called again, and a proper value is entered the second time, choice in main becomes 'none'. Is there any way around this while keeping all these separate functions? I have also tried re-calling show_menu from within itself rather than from within the error function, but it is the same result.

Comment: Don't use recursion for this, use a loop.

Comment: But if you recurse, you need to return a value when recursing: `return show_error(choice)` and `return show_menu()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase of `choice` is invalid, you are calling `show_error`, after executing this function(`show_error`) the interpreter will just move to next line i.e the end of `show_menu` function which implicitly return `None`
.But if you `return show_error()`, the interpreter will execute this function and return whatever value `show_error` will return.

```py
def show_menu():
    choice = input("Burger or Shake?: ")
    if choice not in ["burger", "shake"]:
        return show_error(choice)
    else:
        return choice

def show_error(choice):
    print(f"{choice} is not an option")
    return show_menu()
```

A simpler(more readable) way can be

```py
def read_input():
    return input("Burger or Shake?: ")

def show_menu():
    choice = read_input()
    while choice not in ["burger", "shake"]:
        show_error(choice)
        choice = read_input()
    return choice

def show_error(choice):
    print(f"{choice} is not an option")
```